# Issue with shape on CNN with grayscale images

Tags: python, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I made a CNN for classification with 10 classes.
input = 49000 grayscale pictures, all mixed (I mean training set and validation set)
train.csv contain the list of the images and their labels like this for example :

```
id,label
0.png,4
1.png,9
2.png,1
3.png,7
4.png,3
5.png,9
```

Here a part of the CNN:

```
traindf = pd.read_csv('train.csv', dtype=str)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.25, shear_range = 0.2, zoom_range = 0.2, horizontal_flip = True)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = traindf,
                                              directory='images',
                                              target_size = (28, 28),
                                              color_mode='grayscale',
                                              x_col='id',
                                              y_col='label',
                                              subset='training',
                                              batch_size = 32,
                                              shuffle=True,
                                              class_mode = 'categorical')

valid_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = traindf,
                                              directory="images",
                                              target_size=(28,28),
                                              color_mode='grayscale',
                                              x_col="id",
                                              y_col="label",
                                              subset="validation",
                                              batch_size=32,
                                              shuffle=True,
                                              class_mode="categorical")

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN = train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID = valid_generator.n//valid_generator.batch_size
```

and the fit method:

```
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

classifier.fit_generator(train_generator,
                         steps_per_epoch = STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                         epochs = 10,
                         validation_data = valid_generator,
                         validation_steps = STEP_SIZE_VALID)
```

for the sake of clarity I do not display the creation of the neural networks, but note that input_shape = (28,28,1)

Then I save the model:

```
filepath = './NumChar_model_01'
save_model(classifier, filepath)
```

In another program, I want to predict an image:

```
loaded_model = load_model(filepath,custom_objects=None, compile=True)

img = img.resize((28, 28))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis = 0)
result = loaded_model.predict(img)
```

And I got this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 28, 28, 3]

I know it's an issue with shape, but believe me, I read all the world topic about that...

I tried reshape on train_generator and valid_generator but it give me an error too ('DataFrameIterator' object has no attribute 'reshape')

Comment: If your network input shape is (28,28,1) then you can't send in [None, 28, 28, 3]. I'm guessing your images are color (RGB) images? But your network is expecting grayscale images. For me to be more specific I need to see your model.

Comment: The error message `expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 28, 28, 3]` literally describes the entire problem. The input is expected to have a dimension of  [None, 28, 28, 1], but you fed in data of shape [None, 28, 28, 3].

Comment: Thank you both, i solved my problem. I put the solution into the initial post :)

Comment: If you remove the solution from the question and post it as an answer it will allow you to accept it as an answer. You'll get more points and the question will be marked as solved.

Comment: @JasonAller Thank you very much, I will do this. I am new to the platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

img was gotten by

img = ImageGrab.grab((cx, cy, cx + cw, cy + ch))
It returns an RGB image, which throw the error. So I convert it into a grayscale image with:

img = img.convert('L')
and it works!